# Can't get Paperclip to set my S3 URLs properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using paperclip and aws-sdk gems in a Rails 4 app.

I define the :path option in my paperclip.rb config, with no :url option:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
```

It saves my uploaded images like such:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket-development/profiles/avatars/000/000/026/original/image_file_name.png?1420575189

All fine, it gets saved to S3. However it refuses to let me read the images for display, e.g. =profile.avatar.url(:medium). When I go to that URL in the browser it tells me to re-format it with the bucket name as a domain. Like:

http://mybucket-development.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/avatars/000/000/026/original/image_file_name.png?1420575189

OK, not a problem either. I go to that URL, I can view my image. So now I need to figure out how to get Paperclip to format the URLs like this automatically. I read in the Paperclip docs that you just have to set

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ":s3_domain_url"
```

And that I also have to set the :path parameter or I will just get a Paperclip::Errors::InfiniteInterpolationError.

So I set my config file with both combined:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ":s3_domain_url"
```

Not working... I try scrapping the paperclip.rb and putting it in config/environments/* But no matter what I do, it still saves the URLs without the domain with the bucket name in the path.

So two questions:

1) How can I get Paperclip to automatically format the saved URLs in domain style?

2) Or even better, how can I get S3 to accept the non-domain style URLs, the one that Paperclip is currently generating?

EDIT

So, if I add in the s3_host_name option then it saves the URLs domain style. So I have to have all 3 of:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

And it will save my URLs on the model like so:

http://mybucket-development.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/profiles/avatars/000/000/026/original/image_file_name.png%3F1420580224

But now I see that I have a %3F encoding ("?") in the URL which messes it up.

Comment: Did you create a bucket policy in S3 ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (you answered it below) but I just want to post here as an FYI to anyone who is wondering why they're getting the `Paperclip::Errors::InfiniteInterpolationError` error:

**If you try to change the CDN settings for paperclip you'll get the Infinite Interpolation Error** unless you set the `path` attribute explicitly. You can't change the path or your existing assets won't resolve anymore, so you need to set it to the default path setting. For our paperclip version of `4.3.6`, this value was:
`path: ":class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alright, so as mentioned in the above update, to get the domain-style URLs to be saved by Paperclip I have to include all 3 of the following in my paperclip.rb:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

I believe there is a related issue from recent gem upgrades, this produces URLs with encodings that won't work on their own.

So in my views I have had to add URI.unescape, such as

=image_tag URI.unescape(profile.avatar.url(:medium))

I could also set a callback on the model to replace the %3F with the "?" before save.

Strange issue with Paperclip... not sure what was going on. First app I've worked on where I encountered that issue.

Comment: This works because you're setting :s3_host_name which overrides the other settings.  You can actually remove :url and :path and it still works.  I looked at the source code to paperclip today and it doesn't appear to implement the ':s3_domain_url' logic correctly - or at least, it didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

In paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
```

In production.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
           storage: :s3,
           s3_protocol: :https,
           s3_credentials: {
           bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
           access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
           secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
           s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')
 }
```

This pretty much worked well for me with image_tag. It should work for you too.